# Can not find "GWT Eclipse Plugin" in Eclipse marketplace to install it

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have installed `Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components) Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0) and Build id: 20221201-1913`, when I open Eclipse marketplace and search for `gwt` it can not find `GWT Eclipse Plugin`, so I am unable to install it.
I tried other ways like `drag n drop the` `install button` from [Use the Drag and Drop Install Button](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html#1__Use_the_Drag_and_Drop_Install_Button) and it didn't worked,
also I tried adding the url `http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release` via `Help->Install New Software...` menu and I encountered with error that the url is not reachable.
Today is 12/27/2022 and I have seen reports that the url was available in some time frames but now it is unavailable.

Comment: Does it work with HTTP**S** [`https://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release`](https://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release)?

Comment: No. If you browse your url you get following:

`<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>No such object: gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release</Details>
</Error>`

Comment: Eclipse does not request the directory but files like [`https://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release/content.jar`](https://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release/content.jar) which works for me also in a browser. In Eclipse, just use [`https://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release`](https://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/release).

Comment: Unfortunately it haven't worked for me until I downloaded the zip file and installed it.

Comment: Maybe you are behind a proxy and your Eclipse is not correctly configured (in preferences _General > Network Connections_).

Comment: I just noticed that also http works for me. Does installing other plugins work? I would guess there is something wrong with your settings in preferences _General > Network Connections_.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after many try and error I found how to add `GWT Eclipse Plugin`

> 1-Download the released package from
> http://storage.googleapis.com/gwt-eclipse-plugin/v3/downloads/repo-3.0.0.zip
>
> 2- From `Help->Install New Software...` select a name and select the
> downloaded zip file, then you were able to see `GWT EClipse Plugin` and
> `Google SDK` option, the next steps is straight.

Comment: Hi. Even though the installation works with this method, it seems the editor throws an exception when editing a java class: An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)'. Have you encountered this error also?